# Is there a way to stop myDataSet.HasChanges() returning true if the only change is a new row?

Tags: vb.net, dataset, bindingsource

I have a `Button` on my `Form` that when clicked calls `myBindingSource.AddNew()`. Controls relevant to setting the values on that new row then become visible.

On the close event of that `Form` i call `myDataSet.HasChanges()` and if it returns `True`, i prompt the User if they would like to save the changes they have made.

In the situation where the User clicks to add a new row but then closes the Form, (for whatever reason) without setting any values, `myDataSet.HasChanges()` will return `True` obviously because there is the adding of a new row.

What i would like is a way to make it return `False` if the only change is a new row.

I have tried calling `myBindingSource.EndEdit()` then `myDataSet.AcceptChanges` immediately after `myBindingSource.AddNew()` but `myDataSet.HasChanges()` still returns `True`.

I thought by calling `myDataSet.AcceptChanges()`  it would essentially wipe the slate clean and only changes made after that point would be picked up.

Or alternatively if there is a better approach to this i would like to hear it.

I am keen on the idea of only saving back to the `DataBase` in one go when prompting to save, rather than inserting the new row on the `Button.Click` and updating that row on each value change.

Comment: `HasChanges` is overloaded and allows you to specify a `DataRowState` value, so create a value that excludes `Added`.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your issue is.  The act of calling `BindingSource.AddNew` does add a new record to `BindingSource.DataSource` until edits on that record are committed (`BindingSource.EndEdit`).  This can be confirmed by observing that the number of rows in the backing DataTable is one less than the number of items in the `BindingSource.List` property.  You indicate that you are using multiple controls to represent the record's various fields.  Are you are relying on the addition of the next record to commit the record currently under edit or explicitly committing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more specified than my comment:

```
If myDataSet.HasChanges(DataRowState.Deleted Or DataRowState.Modified) Then
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I am currently kicking myself for not noticing that before!! I can get what i am trying to achieve with this.